# Group By from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement to show a report in the following format from the two different tables as shown below, the below report should count the order numbers by branch.

```
===================================================================
Branch     OrdersCountInTable1           OrdersCountInTable2
===================================================================
    100            5                           2
    200            10                          10
    300            12                          11
```

how can i achieve this using a sqlquery?

Following are the columns in the tables:

```
Table1:
________
 - Branch
 - OrderNo

Table2
__________
 - Branch  
 - OrderNo
```

Table1 Data:

```
===============================
Branch             OrderNo      
===============================
    100            1000                 
    100            1001              
    200            2001
    100            1003
```

Table2 Data:

```
===============================
Branch             OrderNo      
===============================
    100            1000                                    
    200            2001
    100            1003
```

We just want to reconcile orders from both the tables!!
Thanks for any valuable feedbacks.

Comment: can you add some code that creates the 2 tables and adds some sample data so I can look at what you have to work with

Comment: Will it be a ReportingServer report? Just to know if you need to group at source level or you can achieve the result using group functions into the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One *more or less generic* way to do it

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.branch, t2.branch) branch, 
       COALESCE(t1.ordercount, 0) OrdersCountInTable1, 
       COALESCE(t2.ordercount, 0) OrdersCountInTable2
  FROM
(
  SELECT branch, COUNT(orderno) ordercount
    FROM Table1
   GROUP BY branch
) t1 FULL JOIN
(
  SELECT branch, COUNT(orderno) ordercount
    FROM Table2
   GROUP BY branch
) t2
 ON t1.branch = t2.branch
```

*Assumption is that tables may not have entries for all branches. That's why `FULL JOIN` is used.*

Answer (score 0):

Do like this using SUM aggregate function and UNION ALL operator

```
SELECT Branch,
       SUM( CASE tag WHEN 'table1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as OrdersCountInTable1,
       SUM( CASE tag WHEN 'table2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as OrdersCountInTable2
FROM
(

SELECT Branch,'table1' as tag
FROM Table1

UNION ALL

SELECT Branch,'table2' as tag
FROM Table2

) z

GROUP BY Branch
ORDER BY Branch
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a `union` nested query:

```
select 
  Branch, count(Orders1) OrdersCountInTable1, count(Orders2) OrdersCountInTable2
from (
  select Branch,OrderNo Orders1,NULL Orders2 from Table1
  union
  select Branch,NULL Orders1,OrderNo Orders2 from Table2
  ) t
group by Branch
```